# Tutorial about using Neo4js along with Node.js

Tags: node.js, neo4j

Does anyone know about a tutorial or documentation on how to use neo4js in Node.js. I have successfully downloaded it but now I have no clue on how to start using it.

If there is no resources on-line that I can read, could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A wiki about this subject has been made here on SO.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444120/cypher-learning-for-web-devepers

Answer (score 3):

Also,
there is an example app by Thomas Baum with a setup guide, see https://github.com/tbaum/heroku-node-neo4js

Answer (score 3):

For a simplistic application you could start with this:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/node-neo4j-template

For a real tutorial check out this angular + node movie application:

https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-movies-template

Answer (score 2):

I know of is this screen cast - [Johnny and Node.js](https://johnnywengluu.viewscreencasts.com/26a686c9a76242bda83335f6991b27c5) - which shows how to get started on heroku with neo4j and node.js

There is also a [neo4j challenge](http://neo4j-challenge.herokuapp.com/) so you might find some examples come out of that over the next few days check twitter for #neo4jchallenge.

Comment: Thanks.Just starting out of neo4j.They will be helpful.