# Cypher Learning for Web Devepers

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to use Neo4j for my web applications. I am using Node.js for the server side. As I understand, I will have to learn Cypher to query the database.

On the website I could find only a Reference guide. I'm looking for some complete tutorial, at least for the introductory part, regarding the integration of this into the website development process. I don't know Java and I don't want to learn it at the moment.

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I don't know, guys. The 'not constructive' part of this doesn't seem to fit--I don't see it causing arguments or extended discussions. While there are multiple correct answers, I can see others looking for similar advice. I set my answer to community wiki right away, so others could add more resources.

Comment: Yeah I am in the same situation as tc at the moment.So this question is very valuable to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Having some SQL knowledge, this webinar will take you step by step from 0 to beginner: http://watch.neo4j.org/video/60292144
After this, you will have to refer to your own server-side language to complete the integration, but that should be the most effortless part.

Here are some useful beginner knowledge sources:

Watch the webinars about Cypher on:
http://watch.neo4j.org/

Play around in http://console.neo4j.org

Check out the various node.js drivers that support Cypher--I believe the Thingdom one is the most popular:
https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j

Check out examples that use Cypher on Max's blog:
http://maxdemarzi.com/category/cypher/

Luanne posted an excellent guide to query optimization (which may be a bit advanced for newbies, but you should still read it), as well as other Cypher-related posts on the same blog:
http://thought-bytes.blogspot.com/2013/01/optimizing-neo4j-cypher-queries.html

Also, I've posted two introductory blog posts about Cypher just recently, and plan to post more:
http://wes.skeweredrook.com/cypher/

The Graph Databases book:
http://graphdatabases.com/

Feel free to post your newbie Cypher questions here--I'll set this to a community wiki in case anyone has any more resources to add.

Comment: Thank you.I would like to suggest that you add the limited time [free book](http://graphdatabases.com/) as a resource here.

Comment: thanks @WesFreeman, can you please guide me on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try?noredirect=1#comment26496571_17947903 thanks